# Windows SED - Convert tab in csv to pipe with double quotes

Tags: awk, sed, vbscript

I have some data in around 80 columns in CSV file with tab delimiter. I need to convert it in Windows so that all columns are delimited with "\t".
For e.g.

Input:

```
Reporting Standard_WeekName WHS_Code    Operated_by Country_Code    Standard_Customer_Name  Reporting Date  Customer_Region
201824  A05 DUBAI LL NXX    AE  EMEA <next line character> Customer
```

Desired output:

```
"Reporting Standard_WeekName"|"WHS_Code"|"Operated_by"|"Country_Code"|"Standard_Customer_Name"|"Reporting Date"|"Customer_Region"
"201824"|"A05"|"DUBAI"|"LL"|"NXX"|"AE"|"EMEA <next line character> Customer"
```

Please note in the column Customer_region the data is EMEA Customer with next line character between them.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do mention your sample Input and output in CODE TAGS and be clear in your question too.

Comment: Hi Ravinder, the sample file data is: Reporting Standard_WeekName WHS_Code Operated_by Country_Code Standard_Customer_Name Reporting Date Customer_Region
201824 A05 DUBAI LLC NXX AE EMEA

Comment: Kindly do update your post, comments are not meant for that. Also wrap them into CODE TAGS `{}` button while editing them(only codes or samples should be wrapped up in code tags not your question), let me know once done.'

Comment: How can I attach the file here?

Comment: Attaching files or posting images are NOT good practices, please post them by editing your post and wrsp them in code tags by using button `{}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/^/"/' -e 's/$/"/' -e 's/\t/"\t"/g' file > outfile
```

This consists of three different substitutions, passed with the -e command.

The first two replace the beginning(^) and ending($) with a double qoute(")

The third replaces every tab with a tab surrounded by double qoutes

Comment: I am getting an error with the above. Can you please suggest if it works in Windows.     {sed.exe: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `''}

Comment: Windows... I am afraid piping is also unsupported on that platform. Anyway, you can pass each command individually: `sed 's/^/"/' infile >tmpfile1` than: `sed 's/$/"/' tempfile1 >tempfile2` than: `sed 's/\t/"\t"/g'` tempfile2 >outfile. Instead of using sed.exe you can also try to get some kind POSIX subsystem on windows. IIRC this is not so hard on Windows 7 and Windows 10 (Windows 8 is a lot harder)

Comment: Thanks Hielke, Let me try.

Comment: Possibly because of incorrect quoting. I don't know a lot about quoting in cmd or powershell. I found that Windows actually needs double quotes, but you also have to escape the double quote in the parameter, and that might be tricky. I know found this is different in cmd and powershell, and that is hard, no universal answer, and different with different applications. It might save you a lot of headaches if you just use bash for this. If you are on Windows 10 you can quite easily install the linux subsystem on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be (some kind of masochistic) fun to try and do this with the *"tools"* you get with Windows, so save this script as `replace.vbs`:

```
Set TabobjRegEx     = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
TabobjRegEx.Global  = True   
TabobjRegEx.Pattern = "\t"

Do While Not WScript.StdIn.AtEndOfStream
   Line = WScript.StdIn.ReadLine()
   Line = TabobjRegEx.Replace(Line,Chr(34) & Chr(9) & Chr(34))
   Line = Chr(34) & Line & Chr(34)
   WScript.Stdout.WriteLine(Line)
Loop
```

Now you can run:

```
CSCRIPT /NOLOGO replace.vbs < YourFile.txt > NewFile.txt
```

**Notes:**

- RegExp means a regular expression
- Chr(34) means a double quote
- Chr(9) means a TAB

Comment: Thanks Mark, Amazing!! Though I have a small issue with it. When I have next line character in the column it also adds double quotes on it. For e.g. There is a column which has value as {"12/06/2018 16:36:31~Order Enquiry/Change~ ~ ~picked up call/email~PHONE~Mi~ informed~12/06/2018 14:22:54~vh~Follow up call/email.
Kindly update with the details bellow:
Name: Z D
Phone: +91 000000
ETA: Jun 12, 2018 19:00~12/06/2018 13:22:40~ ~ ~ ~Reminder set~12/06/2018 13:21:31~mzi~ ~ ~ ~WH is in "}

Comment: Hi Mark, can this be worked upon with next line characters which are there in few columns? Please suggest.

Comment: I don't know if that's sensibly achievable. In any case, you need to edit your question rather than adding unformatted comments, like @RavinderSingh13 asked you 2 days ago, and ensure it accurately reflects your question and covers all the cases. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Mark!! Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Hi Mark, Did you get a chance to look at the updated question!! Thanks!!